# How do I get a list of available shared mailboxes with Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I can get the messages in a shared mailbox with the

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedinbox@address/messages

endpoint, but is there a way to find all shared inboxes the current user has access to? I could iterate over all users returned from

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

and then attempt to the list the messages from each one and only count the ones that I have access to, but that's not feasible in a system with 1000s of users.

Is there a way to get a list of just the shared inboxes I have access to?